# Connecting Charger + Inverter to deep cycle battery

Tags: battery-charging, backup

It's a really simple question I believe, but I just want to make double sure it's okay. Can one simply clamp a mains charger as well as an inverter onto a deep cycle battery, or does one need any other equipment?

My charger has charge management circuitry. My pure Sine Inverter does inverter things. And the battery is a, well, battery. So can I connect both charger and inverter directly to the terminals of the battery, or do I need to put something between the battery and the inverter?

Not asking about nice-to-have equipment. I really just want to know whether they will work together and play nice.

Comment: Isolator switch.Fuse.

Comment: This is exactly what I've been thinking. Have you found the answer?

Comment: @AriefIbrahimWuller Yes, it turns out you can do that. But, charge controllers have a 12V output and I ended up hooking the inverter into that instead. This means the charge controller will now prevent me from drawing the battery down too far since it will just switch off.